# Symfony2 HWIOAuthBundle do login before a form submision

Tags: php, forms, symfony, oauth-2.0

I successfully installed and setup the HWIOAuthBundle.

I'm wondering how could I show a form to unlogged user and ask him to fill the form and then do Login in with HWIOAuthBundle in the same action. So the user is logged-in and the form submitted in the same action.

Any guidelines on how to achieve this would be a great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just stored the entity to session via Ajax call. And then I followed the HWIOAuthBundle link to the facebook login.

My code:

```
public function submitResultAjaxAction(Request $request)
{
     $entity  = new Entity();
     $form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), $entity);
     $form->bind($request);

     if ($form->isValid()) {
        $session = $this->get("session");
        $session->set('result_entity',$entity);

        $response = array("code" => 100, "success" => true);
        return new Response(json_encode($response));
     }


    $response = array("code" => 500, "success" => false);
    return new Response(json_encode($response));
```